# Can we Insert/Update multiple tables using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have created a database using JPA and Hibernate. There is a table called CHECKPOINT which has four foreign keys meaning it is linked to 4 different tables by a one to one relationship.
 Is there a way to insert/update data in the other four tables without writing an individual query for each and get all four foreign keys for my checkpoint table whenever I insert or update data in the CHECKPOINT table?

Answer (score 0):

Jpa and Hibernate are ORMS, meaning you feel and work with objects rather than the database itself. In case of your question, yes it is possible. consider this example:

```
@Entity(name = "ForeignKeyAssAccountEntity")
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")})
public class AccountEntity implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6790693372846798580L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer accountId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="account")
    private EmployeeEntity employee;

    @Column(name = "ACC_NUMBER", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String accountNumber;

    public Integer getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(Integer accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public EmployeeEntity getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(EmployeeEntity employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
}
```

and the Employee Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "ForeignKeyAssEmployeeEntity")
@Table(name = "Employee", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "EMAIL") })
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154676L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ID")
    private AccountEntity account;

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public AccountEntity getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(AccountEntity account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

*I want to note that this is a One to One relationship. now as you can see these are two separate tables with a relationship. Now I can use hibernate and access both of these tables and make changes then hibernate will match anything I did to the database. Imagine Account of Id=1 is in one to one relationship with an employee of Id=1:

```
@Transactional
public void testUpdates(){
    Account account=entityManager.loadById(Account.class,1);
    account.setAccountNumber("123456");//setting a new number!
    account.getEmployee().setFirstName("a new name!");
}
```

So the above code lets you change or update the two tables, there is no need to write extra code either! you don't even need to call save on account or it's associated employee becuase of the managed state of the entity. I suggest you see a few small samples using JPA/Hibernate and you will see how it is to do what you have in mind. Start [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JR7-EdxDSf0).